# Access HKCU from TAPI Service Provider

Tags: tapi

I am writing an adapter TSP for a phone system. This system has a TAPI API but it is incompatible with the application I am trying to TAPI-enable. In order to place a call from the correct line, I need to know some information (from HKCU) about who is making the request. Since the TSP runs in the context of the Telephony service, I cannot access is directly. My plan was to use the functionality of LINE_CREATEDIALOGINSTANCE to read this information.

The problem I'm having is that the Telephony service is crashing immediately after returning from TUISPI_providerGenericDialog with the following stack trace:

```
72004400() 
tapisrv.dll!_FreeDialogInstance@20()  + 0xa93 bytes 
tapisrv.dll!_ClientRequest@16()  + 0x8f bytes 
rpcrt4.dll!_Invoke@12()  + 0x30 bytes 
rpcrt4.dll!_NdrStubCall2@16()  + 0x217 bytes 
rpcrt4.dll!_NdrServerCall2@4()  + 0x19 bytes 
rpcrt4.dll!_DispatchToStubInCNoAvrf@12()  + 0x17 bytes 
rpcrt4.dll!RPC_INTERFACE::DispatchToStubWorker()  + 0xae bytes 
rpcrt4.dll!RPC_INTERFACE::DispatchToStub()  + 0x4b bytes 
rpcrt4.dll!LRPC_SCALL::DealWithRequestMessage()  + 0x1d5 bytes 
rpcrt4.dll!LRPC_ADDRESS::DealWithLRPCRequest()  + 0x90 bytes 
rpcrt4.dll!LRPC_ADDRESS::ReceiveLotsaCalls()  + 0x20c bytes 
rpcrt4.dll!RecvLotsaCallsWrapper()  + 0xd bytes 
rpcrt4.dll!BaseCachedThreadRoutine()  + 0x92 bytes 
rpcrt4.dll!ThreadStartRoutine()  + 0x1b bytes 
kernel32.dll!_BaseThreadStart@8()  + 0x34 bytes
```

As per [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=3M_mIvtdGqUC&pg=PA215&lpg=PA215&dq=crash+after+TUISPI_providerGenericDialog&source=bl&ots=5TmvB7BREk&sig=nB5Vqb_iib27kjPDSZoL1o8FHkg&hl=en&ei=FZjMSt3NEZWQtgfSl-jxAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3#v=onepage&q=&f=false), the Telephony service will crash if TSPI_providerFreeDialogInstance is not implemented. I have implemented this function and DepWalker shows it as being properly exported. ApiSpy32 shows that its address is correctly returned via GetProcAddress when my TSP is loaded. Why is it still crashing?

The relevant code:

```
LONG TSPIAPI TSPI_lineMakeCall(DRV_REQUESTID dwRequestID, HDRVLINE hdLine, HTAPICALL htCall,
    LPHDRVCALL lphdCall, LPCWSTR lpszDestAddress, DWORD dwCountryCode, LPLINECALLPARAMS const lpCallParams)
{
    OutputDebugString("TSPI_lineMakeCall\n");
    PDRVLINE pLine = (PDRVLINE) hdLine;

    *lphdCall = (HDRVCALL)hdLine;

    typedef TUISPICREATEDIALOGINSTANCEPARAMS PARAMS;

    pLine->htCall = htCall;
    DWORD lLength = (lstrlenW(lpszDestAddress) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);

    PARAMS* lParams = (PARAMS*)DrvAlloc(sizeof(PARAMS) + lLength);
    RtlZeroMemory(lParams, sizeof(PARAMS) + lLength);

    lParams->dwRequestID = dwRequestID;
    lParams->hdDlgInst = (HDRVDIALOGINSTANCE)1000;
    lParams->lpszUIDLLName = L"TapiAdapter.tsp";
    lParams->lpParams = lParams + 1;
    lParams->dwSize = lLength;

    lstrcpyW((LPWSTR)(lParams + 1), lpszDestAddress);
    (*pLine->pfnEventProc)(pLine->htLine, 0, LINE_CREATEDIALOGINSTANCE, (DWORD)lParams, 0, 0);

    return dwRequestID;
}


LONG TSPIAPI TSPI_providerGenericDialogData(DWORD_PTR dwObjectID, DWORD dwObjectType, LPVOID lpParams, DWORD dwSize)
{
    OutputDebugString("TSPI_providerGenericDialogData\n");
    return 0;
}

LONG TSPIAPI TSPI_providerFreeDialogInstance(HDRVDIALOGINSTANCE hdDlgInst)
{
    OutputDebugString("TSPI_providerFreeDialogInstance\n");
    return 0;
}

LONG TSPIAPI TUISPI_providerGenericDialog(TUISPIDLLCALLBACK lpfnUIDLLCallback, HTAPIDIALOGINSTANCE htDlgInst, LPVOID lpParams, DWORD dwSize, HANDLE hEvent)
{
    SetEvent(hEvent);

    LPCWSTR lNumber = (LPCWSTR)lpParams;
    MessageBoxW(0, lNumber, L"Dial Number", MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution: As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725224%28VS.85%29.aspx), the first parameter of the LINEEVENT call **for this event only** needs to be an HPROVIDER, not an HTAPILINE. Since the first parameter of LINEEVENT is of type HTAPILINE, the HPROVIDER will need to be cast.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but the [help for the TUISPICREATEDIALOGINSTANCEPARAMS Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725972(VS.85).aspx) says that `lpszUIDLLName` should be a ...

> pointer to a NULL-terminated string
>   specifying the fully qualified name of
>   the UI DLL to load in the application
>   context

... however `L"TapiAdapter.tsp"` doesn't look like a fully qualified name of the UI DLL ("fully-qualified" means that it includes the path name). Do you *have* a UI DLL to be loaded? *Is* it loaded? Does it display the dialog? Is it unloaded? Does `TUISPI_providerGenericDialog` exist in your TSP, or does it existin your UI DLL (they're supposed to be two different DLLs)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Actually, they do not have to be different DLLs-that part of the code was copied the ATSP sample in the Microsoft TAPI SDK.

I did try the full path. No difference. The problem is not with the UI DLL loading, but after TUISPI_providerGenericDialog returns. This therefore also means that TUISPI_providerGenericDialog is present in my TSP and is being called.